# Parsing Phone Numbers to their parts

Tags: c#, .net, formatting

I know about the C# port of the Google libphonenumber Parsing Library:
http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

What I need is to take a phone number string and break it up into the corresponding pieces, Country Code, Area Code, Prefix, Number, and Extension.

Can this library be used to do that? If so, can someone post a simple test in C# to do that? I don't see how to do it in the docs.

BTW, they can be domestic or international.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The libphonenumber library will parse a number and validate that it matches a known pattern for domestic and international numbers. It will tell you the country code and the correct dialing pattern domestically or internationally for any given number.

It will not parse it into constituent parts beyond that.  No area code, prefix, number, extension parsing.

It's open source so if you need to do this it might be a good starting place, but I'm sure it'll be a huge undertaking.

Comment: Then, do you know of a library that will do that?

Comment: Have you seen the library on CodeProject that is from 2008? I am not sure if it does that, either.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PhoneNumberStruct.aspx?display=Print

Comment: @MB34, nice library, but it separates numbers into parts, it doesn't label the parts country code, prefix, area code, etc.  One really neat thing that library does is handle letters properly, like `1-800-MY-PHONE`.

Answer (score 3):

Patrick Mezard has kindly ported the library to C#:

https://bitbucket.org/pmezard/libphonenumber-csharp/wiki/Home

For usage, you can look at the official web site:

http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

The Java code can be directly translated to C#. For example:

*Java*

```
String swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00"
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
  PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, "CH");
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
  System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}
```

*C#*

```
String swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00";
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
try
{
    PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.Parse(swissNumberStr, "CH");
    Console.WriteLine(swissNumberProto.CountryCode);
}
catch (NumberParseException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.ToString());
}
```

Good luck.

**Update:**

More examples:  http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/source/browse/#svn/trunk/java/libphonenumber/test/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers

If you don't see what you need, then I guess you can implement it yourself.

Comment: I don't see that parsing out the parts. If I pass in the Country Code "CH", why would I need to get is using `swissNumberProto.CountryCode?`

Comment: You need to pull down the library and inspect it. In the example `CH` is for default country code that should be used if the number being parsed doesn't have a country code e.g. +52.